# How to choose text by typing without by selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

Iam using this [choosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) See my working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/juREeL7XjkuTmEg2b4IY?p=preview)

my aim is to achieve that when user types the value and the value should be selected without selecting it.

But on demo i create when i select only it selects the value.  for example when i type planet it is shown and when i select only it shows i want to show by forcing the text after typing when user clicks mouse on the side.
How can i achieve this any work would really appreciable thanks in advance.

The below is my code

```
<script src="//harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="//harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 150px;">
    <select class="chosen-select" style="width: 150px">
        <option>vijay</option>
        <option>sunny</option>
        <option>planet</option>
       <option>airfill</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $(".chosen-select").chosen(); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the OP not an external link because links rot and it would be too much to ask SO people to visit other link just to check your code

Comment: sure i will add now

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags.